# Make a permanent mapping - vb script

Tags: vbscript

What I'm trying to accomplish is:

I'm having a workgroup server with home directories for three persons, these home directories needs to be mapped from their workstations using a vbs.

1. Retrieve the username of the user logged on
2. Make a permanent mapping (stays after a relogon or reboot) for \wgserver\homes\, where the username is the username of the logged on user retrieved

Basically whats happening is nothing, no error message or anything, which left me puzzled, any tips to solve this will be greatly appreciated!

---

```
Option Explicit
Dim objNetwork
Dim wshShell
Dim strUserName

Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set wshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

strUserName = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERNAME%")

Dim strDriveLetter
Dim strRemotePath

strDriveLetter = "H:"
strRemotePath = "\\wgserver\Homes\%username%"

objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive strDriveLetter, strRemotePath
```

Comment: Ok then what is your problem?

Comment: have you tried `strRemotePath = "\\wgserver\Homes\" & strUserName`?

Comment: Yes, it makes no difference, no error message or anything

Answer (score 0):

You've already expanded `%USERNAME%` and returned the username string to your `strUserName` variable. So just concatenate that value to your path:

Change:

```
strRemotePath = "\\wgserver\Homes\%username%"
```

To:

```
strRemotePath = "\\wgserver\Homes\" & strUserName
```

To store the mapping in the user's profile, set the 3rd param to `True`. See the [MapNetworkDrive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kst88h6%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) function for more info:

```
objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive strDriveLetter, strRemotePath, True
```

Comment: This sounds reasonable, I will try it out and give you feedback when I have access to my server-setup, thx for taking the time to answer me.